# How to check if object is Transferable?

Tags: javascript, abstract-class, postmessage, transferable

I have written this function to get all [transferable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Transferable_objects) elements of an Object — and to get them *without* duplicates, so the list can actually be used with `postMessage()`.

It includes a check against a pseudo-[Abstract Base Class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_type) which does lookup against a *hard-coded whitelist* of known "Transferable" types. This is obviously a nasty, kludgy, **fragile** hack.

I've written this function because I was unable to find any *actual* API for doing this check. Does any exist?

```js
function getTransferables(obj, seen=null) {
    seen ||= new WeakSet();

    if (typeof obj !== 'object')
        // Non-transferable leaf
        return [];

    if (seen.has(obj))
        // Avoid infinite loop on cyclic objects
        return [];
    seen.add(obj);
 
    if (obj instanceof _Transferable)
        // Transferable leaf
        return [obj];

    // Recurse
    return Object.entries(obj).flatMap(([,obj]) => getTransferables(obj, seen));
}

// FIXME ugly hack
const _Transferable = Object.assign([
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Transferable_objects#supported_objects
    'ArrayBuffer',
    'MessagePort',
    'ReadableStream',
    'WritableStream',
    'TransformStream',
    'WebTransportReceiveStream',
    'WebTransportSendStream',
    'AudioData',
    'ImageBitmap',
    'VideoFrame',
    'OffscreenCanvas',
    'RTCDataChannel'
].map(clsName => {
    "use strict";
    if (!this)
        throw new RuntimeError('could not get global scope');
    return this[clsName];
}).filter(cls => cls), {
    [Symbol.hasInstance](obj) {
        return this.some(cls => obj instanceof cls);
    }
});
```

```html
<button onclick="{

let a = new ArrayBuffer(69),
    b = new ArrayBuffer(42);

let myObj = ({x: {a, b}, y: {a_again: a}});

let myTransfer = getTransferables(myObj);

console.info(`There are ${myTransfer.length} Transferables in ${JSON.stringify(myObj, (k,v) =&gt; {if (v instanceof _Transferable) return ({[`!${v.__proto__.constructor.name}`]: {}}); return v;})}.`);

}">Demo</button>
```

Comment: you could try to test instances/prototypes/data with structuredClone https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Transferable_objects#transferring_during_a_cloning_operation